# How do I calculate the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2-x)^k}{2^k\cdot k}$ in every x in (0, 4)?

Tags: convergence-divergence, derivatives, summation

Well I've been trying to search for the appropriate derivative but I couldn't find it

Thanks

Comment: Set $t:=\frac {2-x}2$ and think logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2-x)^k}{2^k\cdot k},
$$
we have for every $x \in (0,4)$:
$$
f'(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2-x)^{k-1}}{2^k}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2-x)^k}{2^k}=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(1-x/2)}=-\frac{1}{x}.
$$
It follows that
$$
f(x)=-\ln x+c,
$$
with $-\ln2+c=f(2)=0$, i.e. $c=\ln2$. Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2-x)^k}{2^k\cdot k}=-\ln x+\ln2.
$$

Comment: This is just $\ln\frac{2}{x}$.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes it is, so what's your point?